# How can I customize exception formatting in jest in order to pretty-print my Error subclasses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, jestjs

Writing tests in node.js, I would like to hook into jest to allow custom formatting of unhandled exceptions.  I want to do that to pretty-print subclasses of Error that I throw in the code under test.  Currently I only see the message property of the base Error get printed on test failure, because for reasons outside my control the subclasses are defined like this:

```
class SomeCustomError extends Error {
    constructor(custom, stuff, message) {
        super(message);
        this._custom = custom;
        this._stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

For example, I imagine defining toString methods on certain exceptions, and then configuring a jest custom error handler, which would call error.toString() and then print the return value (or a custom formatter, which would return the return value):

```
    toString(): {
        return `${this._custom} ${this._stuff} ${this._message}`
    }
```

then maybe something like (in `jest.config.js`):

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    unhandledErrorFormatterHook: (error) => `A jest test raised an unhandled exception: ${error.toString()}`,
    ...
}
```

How can I do that for every test?  Rather than decorating every test case using a higher-order function directly in my test code, I'd prefer to use built-in jest features to do this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with a [custom `Reporter`](https://jestjs.io/docs/25.x/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options).

The catch with a custom reporter is the original `Error` is serialized into a plain object.  Any non enumerable properties of the error are removed like the type, `stack`, `message` and `name` so it might involve some duck typing to detect when a `SomeCustomError` has occurred.

For any tests with a `status` of `failed`, a `failureDetails` array will be populated containing the serialized error object.
Any of the [Reporter interface](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/be501e1029c86f9da539e13798f8da77bb71211d/packages/jest-reporters/src/types.ts) functions that receive a `TestResult` will be able to access the `failureDetails` array directly. Otherwise in an `AggregatedResult` via:

```
aggregate_result.testResults[].testResults[].failureDetails[]
```

There is also the `failureMessages` property of a `TestResult` that contains a similar array but of the stringified errors, which does include the `name`, `message` and `stack` information.

`MyCustomReporter.js`

```js
function logTestFailureDetails(test_result){
  if (test_result.status !== 'failed') return
  console.log('Failed test:', test_result.fullName)
  for (const err of test_result.failureDetails) {
    // err will have the properties, like `_custom` and `_stuff`. 
    console.log('failureDetails', err)
  }
}

class MyCustomReporter {
  
  // After each test
  onTestCaseResult(test, test_result, aggregate_result){
    console.log('MyCustomReporter onTestCaseResult:')
    logTestFailureDetails(test_result)
  }

  // Summary at the end
  onRunComplete(contexts, results) {
    console.log('MyCustomReporter onRunComplete:')
    for (const aggregate_result of results.testResults) {
      aggregate_result.testResults.forEach(logTestFailureDetails)
    }
  }

}

module.exports = MyCustomReporter
```

Jest `package.json` config

```
{
  "jest": {
    "reporters": [
      "<rootDir>/MyCustomReporter.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

It would be worth setting well defined codes on the the custom errors so they can be detected easily. Maybe even the `name` if you don't mind the error `name` becoming enumerable elsewhere.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(message){
    super(message)
    this.code = 'CNX'
    this.name = this.constructor.name
  }
}
```

It might also be possible to extend the jest [DefaultReporter](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/be501e1029c86f9da539e13798f8da77bb71211d/packages/jest-reporters/src/DefaultReporter.ts) and friends to produce the required output. The [failure message appears to be generated in the core code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/bc84c8a15649aaaefdd624dc83824518c17467ed/packages/jest-core/src/TestScheduler.ts#L160) though, so it might take some string manipulation in the reporters to get you there.